# USB modem device software in cisco routers using C

Tags: c, tcl, router, cisco

HI all,

I am a final year computer science student; my project for final year is to develop a software using C or Tcl, for a CISCO router. In the latest series of routers, cisco has given a USB port for mass storage.
Now I want that if I plug-in a wireless modem like Idea netsetter (a modem available in India with this name), the router should connect to the internet.

Tell me any basic ideas regarding this project. Also, if there is any other language in which it can be developed more easily, please suggest.

Comment: So, you're wanting the router to support using the external wireless connection (GSM?) as a default route? (Just trying to clear up what you're asking for, and in the process give you some of the terminology to use when talking to experts. I'm *not* an expert on routers!)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the modem? Data? SMS?

Comment: Actually what i am trying to do is, I want this usb interface to be a connection to the internet, which is only possible when i use a Usb modem device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "develop a software using C or Tcl, for a CISCO router", do you mean that you are writing a custom firmware from scratch?  Or are you wanting to write some sort of plug-in or application that interfaces with the existing firmware?

In either case, I would recommend that you first consult the documentation you have for the router.  See what kind of API and driver support you have for the C and TCL languages.  If one language looks like it is better supported than the other, then you will likely have an easier time using that language.

In my experiences, it is typically easier to do systems-level programming in C than in TCL.  Most embedded systems assume that you are going to work in C and provide C-language interfaces to system functions.  You didn't mention anything about the router model, so I can't say anything too specific.